# Does a dynamic prepared statement makes sense?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, prepared-statement, pg, node-postgres

I want to create dynamic prepared statements, that every part is dynamic, the values, the table and the WHERE part.

I use nodejs + PostgreSQL and the pg module to talk to the PostgreSQL. The pg module offers a different syntax to go along with node.js , but I guess the principles are the same. This is based to the official example [here](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#prepared-statements)

```
//dynamic that can change 
let select = 'name , email, age';
let table = 'user';
let where = 'id=$1 AND gender=$2';
let values = [1,'female'];

//prepare
const query = {
  // give the query a unique name  
  name: 'fetch-user',
  text: 'SELECT' + select + 'FROM' + table + 'WHERE' + where,
  values: values
}

//execute
client.query(query)
  .then(res => console.log(res.rows[0]))
  .catch(e => console.error(e.stack))
```

I was wondering if this will make sense , **performance-wise**.

I red the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html) and , what I understand is that by having all the parts of a prepared statement dynamic, then the planning may be not so effective , or not effective at all.

What should I do? Should I keep this dynamic syntax? Or it doesn't make any sense, so I have to create multiple prepared statements and use them for different tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There should be no performance issues here. The "dynamic" part of your SQL is just a string you're passing into the query object, so the only performance to consider is resolving the text property. You're passing your database a fully prepared statement; it's nodejs that is resolving the different variables to come up with the query object's text property.

Comment: Great, because, from what I understood, in order for the prepared statements to be fast, the only dynamic part has to be the WHERE and the values, and not the rest.

Comment: Oh wait, maybe I didnt my self clear. The value of each of the select, table, where, values will change  according to what function they are in

Comment: @codebot, that's fine. Again, those values are getting resolved by nodejs before the query is handed off to your SQL platform.